# MySQL - record farthest trip

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Assuming I have the following 2 tables:

trips:

`driverId (PK), dateTravelled, totalTravelDistance`

farthest_trip (same structure)

`driverId (PK), dateTravelled, totalTravelDistance`

where **only the most recent journey** is stored:

`REPLACE INTO JOURNEYS ('$driverId', '$totalTripDistance');`

I want to store the farthest trip travelled for each driverId as well, but unfortunately you can't have a condition on an `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement, or else I'd have a trigger such as:

`INSERT INTO farthest_trip(driverId, dateTravelled, totalTravelDistance) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dateTravelled = new.dateTravelled, totalTravelDistance = new.totalTravelDistance WHERE totalTravelDistance < new.totalTravelDistance;`

so what I do is after inserting into the first table, in PHP  I check if the current distance is farther than the one previously recorded, and if so, then update farthest_journey. It feels like there should be a better way but I can't quite figure it out, so is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a trigger. Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER farhest_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON trips
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE farthest_trips SET date=NEW.date, distance=NEW.distance WHERE driverId=NEW.driverId AND distance < NEW.distance;
  END;
```

But then you would have code that gets executed "magically" from a PHP perspective.

I think the better solution would be appending new trips to the trips table and selecting the maximum and latest journey with SELECT statements.

Comment: I don't mind the magic part ;) however, a) we can't store all trips since there'd be millions, and b) the update fails because for the first trip there won't be an entry in farthest_trip.

Comment: Instead of the UPDATE in the trigger, use an INSERT with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause.